# @Header and spring stream functional programming model

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Is there a way to use **@Header** inside the following kafka consumer code ? I am using **Spring Cloud Stream (Kafka Stream binder implementation)**, and there after my implemention is using **functional model** for example.

```
@Bean
public Consumer<KStream<String, Pojo>> process() {
    return messages -> messages.foreach((k, v) -> process(v));
}
```

If using **Spring for apache kafka** then this can be as simple as

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${mytopicname}", clientIdPrefix = "${myprefix}", errorHandler = "customEventErrorHandler")
public void processEvent(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key,
                         @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
                         @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                         @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) long ts
                         @Valid Pojo pojo) {
    ...
    // use headers here
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; the Kafka Streams binder is not based on Spring Messaging.

You can access headers, topic, and such in a `Transformer` (via the `ProcessorContext`) added to your stream.

You can use the Kafka Message Channel binder with

```java
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<Pojo>> process() {
    return message -> ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, ProcessorContext had all the info that i needed (headers, topicName etc)

Comment: can you please share the code? how did you get the processContext using transform().

Comment: See the javadocs for `Transformer`; the context is passed into the `init()` method.

Comment: hello Gary, i am able to write the code but getting nontrustedheader at TopicHeader line: 
@Bean
public java.util.function.Consumer<Message<Avro>> consumeDelayService() {
  return message -> {
    TopicHeader topic = message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECORD_METADATA, TopicHeader.class);
    Avro payload = (Avro) message.getPayload();
  };
}

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's too hard to read; and don't ask new questions in comments anyway; it doesn't help people find questions/answers. Ask a new question with much more detail.